# Is there a way to change AI level in Play mode in Heroes of the Storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I know you can change the level of the AI in custom games, but when you fill your game with AI in Play mode can you change the level of the AI?
What I read and looked through made it look static but a lot of the documentation seemed to be somewhat dated (old beta forum posts) and I thought maybe I was missing something obvious in the interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's only one level of AI in Play mode.  There's no way to change it when you queue right now.

Edit: As of the patch on 8/18/15, you can now select the AI difficult from a dropdown menu on the Versus AI screen

Comment: http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/19818499/heroes-of-the-storm-patch-notes-august-18-2015-8-18-2015#User_Interface (Versus A.I. section).  Thanks for the edit/update!

Comment: Do you know if you'll be matched with other Players who have selected the same difficulty level?

Comment: You will be matched with other players who selected your difficulty...unless you are playing off-peak hours and there aren't enough players in the queue (more noticeable at higher difficulties).  If that happens, each player will have one opponent at their specified difficulty level.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as part of [August 18, 2015 patch](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/19818499/heroes-of-the-storm-patch-notes-august-18-2015-8-18-2015)

> A difficulty dropdown has been added to the Versus A.I. screen, which can be used to switch among five different A.I. difficulty settings: Beginner, Recruit, Adept, Veteran, and Elite.